# Web API action cache

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a cache mechanism for some WebAPI actions. i found the following option is useful but i am not sure its the best way:

1. I am going to use context.Cache["[Here i will set the action name and the values of all the parameters passed to the action]"] = [here i will set the result i got from the database] in a Filter i will build.
2. The action filter will search the string of the action name and the parameters in the context.Cache collection. if exists, will return the data instead of executing the original action.

Is that the best approach?

Btw, i prefer to not use any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Why not use standard caching mechanism of MVC? Or it is not available in Web Api? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Its not available for WebAPI as far as i know. you are talking about [OutputCache] right?

Comment: Yes, for some reason i thought that it is available in Web Api.

Comment: Maybe this article will help http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/output-caching-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Dear Yevgeniy, thanks for the response but i prefer to not use any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: The author of this post provides you with ability to download his solution using Nuget.
But you can also write all code by yourself by following his instructions.